# protobuf-net implicit contracts

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

Does anyone have a working example where protobuf-net can be used as a drop-in replacement for BinaryFormatter? Is that even possible?

Actually I just need a serializer for one message type which looks like

```
public class A {
  public B[] Bs { get;set; }
  public C[] Cs { get;set; }
}
```

All types are defined in a different assembly and have a lot of properties.
Is there an option to automatically generate proto contracts with all public properties included, for class A and other used types (B, C), so something like

```
var formatter = ProtoBuf.Serializer.CreateFormatter<A>()
```

just works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, protobuf-net is not intended to be, and does not claim to be, a 100% drop in replacement for `BinaryFormatter`. It has slightly different features.

Would you be content to do a little reflection? Basically, there is support for `ImplicitFields`, but currently this is only available via `[ProtoContract]`, and cannot be done conveniently via `RuntimeTypeModel`, which is a bit of a pain, and is on my list. Although, I should point out that I consider implicit-fields to be a bit risky, and it should only be done if you know the DTO innards won't change! But: to answer your question, you could iterate over the types you expect, and add them to the model manually:

```
static void Main()
{
    Prepare(typeof(A), typeof(B), typeof(C));
    // if you really want to use IFormatter...
    var formatter = RuntimeTypeModel.Default.CreateFormatter(typeof (A));
    var obj = new A {Bs = new B[] {new B()}};
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        formatter.Serialize(ms, obj);
        ms.Position = 0;
        var clone = formatter.Deserialize(ms);
    }
}
static void Prepare(params Type[] types)
{
    if(types != null) foreach(var type in types) Prepare(type);
}
static void Prepare(Type type)
{
    if(type != null && !RuntimeTypeModel.Default.IsDefined(type))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Preparing: " + type.FullName);
        // note this has no defined sort, so invent one
        var props = type.GetProperties(); 
        Array.Sort(props, (x, y) => string.Compare(
            x.Name, y.Name, StringComparison.Ordinal));
        var meta = RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(type, false);
        int fieldNum = 1;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < props.Length ; i++)
        {
            meta.Add(fieldNum++, props[i].Name);
        }

    }
}
```

Note that the use of `IFormatter` here is entirely unnecessary; you could also use `RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Serialize(...)` or `Serializer.Serialize<T>(...)`.

As a footnote: I would *advise* defining the models more ... repeatably. For example:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(A)).Add("Bs", "Cs");
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(B)).Add("Foo");
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(C)).Add("Bar", "Blap", "Blop");
```

Comment: Thanks, I hoped to get an answer directly from you. Just didn't expect it so soon :). One more question. If fieldNum = props[i].Name.GetHashCode() ^ props[i].PropertyType.GetHashCode() would that be more safe as fieldNum would change if name or type of the property changes...

Comment: One more thing. Do you see anything wrong to call Prepare recursively for unknown types found in properties?

Comment: @Marko 1: hash-codes are not guaranteed to be unique, 2: hash-codes are not guaranteed to be the same between AppDomains, and 3: field-encoding means that low field numbers are **greatly** preferred. Small numbers can be single-byte; larger numbers can be multi-byte. This is to do with "varint encoding", noting that the number is lef-shifted 3 places by this point, so field 1 is *encoded* as a number between 8 and 15 ("which" depends on the data-type, which is what goes in the other 3 bits)

Answer (score 4):

This is the final version of Prepare function I used:

```
static void Prepare(params Type[] types)
        {
            foreach (var type in types)
            {
                if (type != null && !RuntimeTypeModel.Default.IsDefined(type))
                {
                    if (type.Namespace.StartsWith("System"))
                        return;

                    Debug.WriteLine("Preparing: " + type.FullName);
                    // note this has no defined sort, so invent one
                    var props = type.GetProperties();
                    Array.Sort(props, (x, y) => string.Compare(
                        x.Name, y.Name, StringComparison.Ordinal));
                    var meta = RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(type, false);
                    int fieldNum = 1;
                    for (int i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
                        if (props[i].CanWrite)
                        {                            
                            meta.Add(fieldNum++, props[i].Name);

                            if (!RuntimeTypeModel.Default.IsDefined(props[i].PropertyType))
                                if (props[i].PropertyType.HasElementType)
                                    Prepare(props[i].PropertyType.GetElementType()); //T[]
                                else if (props[i].PropertyType.IsGenericType)
                                    Prepare(props[i].PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()); //List<T>
                                else
                                    Prepare(props[i].PropertyType);
                        }
                }
            }
        }
```

If somebody is interested, this is the result of my benchmark (serialize + deserialize):

```
BinaryFormatter      10000 messages: 2.131s  5028 bytes/msg
Json.NET Bson        10000 messages: 1.679s  1071 bytes/msg
MetSys Bson          10000 messages: 1.581s  1035 bytes/msg
Protobuf             10000 messages: 0.145s   109 bytes/msg
MsgPack              10000 messages: 0.844s   106 bytes/msg
```

Notes:

- MetSys.Bson library does not handle decimal type well.
- MsgPack library has problems with read-only properties

Thanks Marc for your help and such a great library.

Comment: Just for info, there are sometimes ways of tightening it *even further* if you need, but it requires an in-advance understanding of the data you are serializing, *and* a broad understanding of protobuf. For example, there are "packed" arrays, different choices of data sub-formats, etc. I've tried to select the defaults as a reasonable "it'll work ok for most things" selection.

Comment: I'm already very happy with these results, both serialization time and message size are 10x smaller than BSON. Wow. I guess it works so well because fields are mostly numeric. Thanks again!

Comment: actually, if your **arrays** (or lists) are things like `int[]`/`float[]`/etc, then you can actually make a significant improvement by setting `IsPacked = true` on the `ValueMember`. This is an optimized encoding for arrays-of-primitives.